# uniform distribution fitting in matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, model-fitting

I have a data set and would like to fit them to uniform distribution and calculate goodness of fit with Matlab. However, I found that uniform is not included in function '**fitdist**'. Is there any method to do uniform distribution fitting in Matlab?

Comment: I was just wondering if my answer was any use to you? If not, please let me know why and perhaps I can improve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

When you say you would like to fit the dataset to the uniform, I'm assuming that what you mean is that you would like to estimate the parameters of a uniform distribution that best fit your dataset.

This is actually quite an interesting question. I'm not surprised that `fitdist` was no help as the uniform distribution is a bit of a special case. For example, it can be shown that under some circumstances, the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameters of a uniform distribution does not exist, and under other circumstances, has no unique solution.

So, what to do? Well, a uniform distribution has two parameters, `a` and `b`, which define the lower and upper bound of the density. Let `X` denote your dataset (say, a column vector of observations). A naive estimator of `a` and `b` is:

```
a = min(X);
b = max(X);
```

Of course these estimates will over-estimate (for `a`) and under-estimate (for `b`) the true parameters almost surely, since it is unlikely that a random sample drawn from the density will fall right on  the boundary.

For the case where it is known that `a` is 0, the minimum variance unbiased estimator of `b` is:

```
b = max(X) + (max(X) / length(X))
```

This estimator is related to the famous [German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). For the general case, I don't actually know any estimation theory (although I'm sure there must be some). My first guess would be to use the naive min/max estimator, but subtract and add the average distance between the observations in your dataset, ie:

```
a = min(X) - c;
b = max(X) + c;
```

where

```
c = (max(X) - min(X)) / length(X)
```

As for goodness-of-fit, hopefully someone else on SO knows something, as I'd need to do a fair bit of research myself to answer that. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Further to Colin's answer, goodness of fit for uniform distribution can be calculated using a [Pearson's chi-squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Goodness_of_fit).

If you have access to the Matlab stats toolbox you can perform this fairly simply by using the [chi2gof](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/chi2gof.html) function. Example 3 in the documentation shows how to apply it to a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Transform your variable to a normal distributed variable and use "kstest". 
So if you have a variable X that is uniform from a to b make the following code

`X_uni=(X-a)/(b-a); %Uniform 0,1 variable`

```
X_norm=norminv(X_uni); % transform to normal distributed variable
[h,P]=kstest(X_norm) ; %P is the test statistic
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand of Alan answer, to know how to properly used [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)

## Setting Parameters

```
N=100; % sample size
a=0; % lower boundary
b=1; % higher boundary
```

Sample N uniformly distributed values between a and b. And in the second line add some bais to make it not uniform if you want to test the code.

```
x=unifrnd(a,b,N,1);
%x(x<.9) = rand(sum(x<.9),1);
```

## Using [`chi2gof`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html)

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996380/uniform-distribution-fitting-in-matlab), with [`chi2gof`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html), you can't use the 'cdf of the hypothesized distribution' and need to specified the bins, the edges and the expected values.

```
nbins = 10; % number of bin
edges = linspace(a,b,nbins+1); % edges of the bins
E = N/nbins*ones(nbins,1); % expected value (equal for uniform dist)

[h,p,stats] = chi2gof(x,'Expected',E,'Edges',edges)
```

## Using [`chi2cdf`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2cdf.html)

With this function you need to supply the chi-squared test statistic, $\displaystyle \chi ^{2}$ which can be computed with the function `histogramm`:

```
h = histogram(x,edges);
chi = sum((h.Values - N/nbins).^2 / (N/nbins));
k = nbins-1; % degree of freedom
chi2cdf(chi, k)
```

Note, that if you don't use the edges to compute the number of value per bins, `histogramm` will choose them from the lower value to the highest and therefore the final score will be different than with `chi2gof`

At the end, you want to use the p value to answer the question "Can I safely *reject* the null hypothesis (i.e. `x` is not a coming from a uniform distribution) ? ". 
Yes, you can safely say that `x` is *not* coming from a uniform distribution if `p` is lower than a [significant level (alpha)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).